# Pipelight for Opera/Chrome? Watching HBO Nordic..

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, streaming, pipelight

I am trying to stream on HBONordic with is a mess.

I managed to finally getting it working with firefox by installing `pipelight-plugin`, enabling flash, widevine, and silverlight. And lastly, running `sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins`.

Is there any way to replicate this in Opera? I would very much prefer NOT using Firefox just to stream.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful or even relevant, but [Chrome doesn't support NPAPI plugins anymore](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en).

Comment: Also Firefox will [drop support of most NPAPI plugins](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/) at the end of 2016, and Pipelight is [no more developed since 2014](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mqchael/pipelight/master/files), so it will soon be useless also for Firefox.

Comment: Well, that sucks... Hopefully HBO Nordic will develop themselves out of 2009 technology at some point. But both their app and web page really suck, so..

Answer (score 0):

Look like HBO Nordic need to work only new Flash player and Widevine. So both lack in Firefox for Linux yet. We have only Flash 11.2 so far but on Google Chrome side we have new Flash 2X and support for native Widevine.

So you in theory you should able to watch it but only on Chrome (or even on Chromium, Vivaldi or Opera if you correct load Widevine and Flash plugin).
Try it. I can't because HBO Nordic only allow scandinavia users :/

Comment: Chrome doesn't work for me. It just doesn't load the video at all.